# tensorflow-gpu ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to load a model from a .h5 file(trained by mobilenetv2).

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
class Classifier(object):

    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.model = models.load_model(model_path)
```

Code of my model:

```
model_pre = keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=False,
)

model_pre.trainable = False

last_output = model_pre.output

x = Flatten()(last_output)
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x) 
model = tf.keras.Model(model_pre.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

tensorflow-gpu == 2.2 (with 2.3 same problem)
python == 3.8.3

after loading i get this problem

```
2020-10-12 21:37:39.500606: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/manos/projects/gesture_recognition/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    classifier = Classifier(CLASSIFIER_MODEL_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\manos\projects\gesture_recognition\classifier\gesture_classifier.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.model = models.load_model(model_path)
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 177, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 361, in deserialize_keras_object
    (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
  File "C:\Users\manos\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 321, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

Everywhere I looked at solutions to this problem they wrote about upgrading or downgrading version of tensorflow-gpu, but not one option didn't help me

Comment: Not fully clear... what does "trained by mobilenetv2" mean? Is it actually a mobilenetv2 model? Did you train it? Or does it contain default "imagenet" weights?

Comment: I used transfer training to train my classifier. I added code of my model

Comment: Do you use just ````tf.keras.models.save_model(model)```` to save your model or you do something else before saving? It may be that the problem has to do with the optimizer. When you save the model try to set ````tf.keras.models.save_model(model, include_optimizer=False)````

Comment: I saved model with include_optimzer `model.save("model.h5', include_optimizer=False)` and get same problem.

Comment: I train in google colab, but I upload the model on my computer. In colab, the model loads without problems.

Comment: Ok. I ve checked right now, the default python version in Colab in my case is 3.6.9. The last suggestion would be also to downgrade your python to match the colab.

Also when you load the model, you can try to provide the custom_objects parameter ````load_model(model_path, custom_objects)````. Maybe it helps just to fake the Functional like that ````custom_objects = {"Functional" : ""}```` but probably not.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the Python version helped, but now it's very long `Adding visible gpu devices: 0`. Probably worth putting in a separate question, because again nothing helps(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as I was saving the model using the import: `from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint` but loading the saved model only using the import `from keras.models import load_model`. Once I changed it to `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model` it worked fine.